# Scraping JSON arrays nested tags

Tags: python, arrays, json, web-scraping, urllib

I am trying to scrape data from a JSON file. I am able to scrape data from some of the tags but few nested tags are giving problem. Following is a sample from the file -

```
{"orders":[{
  "order_id":9000,
  "flight_start":"2017-06-15T05:00:00.000Z",
  "flight_end":"2017-06-22T05:00:00.000Z",
  "spots":[{
      "spot_id":7354259,
      "spot_length":15}],
  "constraints":{
      "forbid":[{
        "network":"BRVO"},
        {"network":"DSE"},
        {"network":"ESPN"},
        {"network":"DFC"},
        {"hours":[2,6],
         "days_of_week":["Monday","Tuesday","Thursday","Friday"]},
        {"hours":[2,6],
         "days_of_week":["Saturday","Sunday"]}],
      "allocation":[{
         "hours":[6,9],
         "impressions":{
             "min":0.05,
             "max":0.05},
         "days_of_week":["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday"]},{
         "hours":[20,0],
         "impressions":{"min":0.5,"max":0.5},
         "days_of_week":["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday"]},{
         "budget":{
             "min":1,
             "max":1},
         "spot_length":15}]}}]}
```

I am not able to scrape all values from network tag, it is only returning top value from all the network tabs for each order.

I am using the following code -

```
 import urllib
 import json
 url = 'http://vw-test.elasticbeanstalk.com/test'
 json_obj = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('UTF-8')
 data = json.loads(json_obj)
 for i in data["orders"]:
     k = i["order_id"]
     j = i["flight_start"]
     l = i["flight_end"]
     m = i ['spots']
     for  value in m:    
         a = value["spot_length"]
         b = value["spot_id"]
     n = i["constraints"]
     c = n["forbid"]
     d = c[0]
     e = d["network"]
     print(e)
```

If any one could help me figure this out I'll be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The json data in your question isn't complete. Making some assumptions, this could work:

```
for i in data["orders"]:
    k = i["order_id"]
    j = i["flight_start"]
    l = i["flight_end"]
    m = i ['spots']
    for  value in m:
        a = value["spot_length"]
        b = value["spot_id"]
    n = i["constraints"]
    c = n["forbid"]
    d = c[0]
    networks = [d["network"] for d in c if "network" in d]
    print(networks)
```

Comment: yes this works, thanks a lot. BTW the link to the json file is given in the code if you want to take a look.

Comment: You're welcome. I just meant that the sample data shown _in your question_ needed to end with `"spot_length":15}]}}]}` to be well-formed.

Comment: yeah you are right sorry about that, I have fixed it in the question. Thank you so much